# Syntax to create Dictionary in Swift

Tags: swift, swift-playground

As far as I know there are two ways to create an empty dictionary in swift

```
var randomDict = [Int:Int]()
```

or

```
var randomDict = Dictionary<Int, Int>()
```

Is there any difference between these? Both versions seems to work just the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, both are same.
From [Apple's Book on Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html):

> The type of a Swift dictionary is written in full as `Dictionary<Key, Value>`
>   You can also write the type of a dictionary in shorthand form as `[Key: Value]`. Although the two forms are functionally identical, **the shorthand form is preferred**.

So

```
var randomDict = [Int:Int]()
```

and

```
var randomDict = Dictionary<Int, Int>()
```

both calls the initializer which creates an empty dictionary  and are basically the same in different form.

Answer (score 1):

A third way you could do it is:

```
var randomDict:[Int:Int] = [:]
```

They're all equivalent as far as the code goes.  I prefer one of the shorthand versions.