# Dictionary<String, Any> vs. [String: Any]

Tags: objective-c, arrays, swift, dictionary

Currently, in Swift 3, there are 2 ways to write dictionary types. These are `Dictionary<String, Any>` and `[String: Any]`. I know that the former is compatible with Objective-C key/value coding and the latter is not but other than this are there any major differences between them or any performance implications I should be aware of?

I am currently swaying towards using the former for its Obj-C key/val compatibility but please warn me if this is a slippery slope.

I suppose the same could be said for `Array<String>` and `[String]` too?

Comment: The is no difference at all between `Dictionary<String, Any>` and `[String: Any]`, or between `Array<String>` and `[String]`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29354511/syntax-to-create-dictionary-in-swift, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34240602/difference-between-string-and-arraystring.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Dictionary<String, Any>` and `[String: Any]`, `Array<String>` and `[String]` are same. There is no difference at all.

Answer (score 2):

Dictionary and [String: Any] are different syntax for the same thing. If you want key-value coding you can use NSDictionary or NSArray.

```
var swiftarray: Array = []
// Fill the array with objects
var array: NSArray = (swiftarray as NSArray).valueForKeyPath("key.path") as NSArray
```